# Could not get localhost address

Tags: moqui

```
Initializing Moqui ExecutionContextFactoryImpl
- runtime directory: /home/doman/testMoqui/MoquiEcosystem-1.6.2/runtime
- config file: /home/doman/testMoqui/MoquiEcosystem-1.6.2/runtime/conf/MoquiDevConf.xml
--- 16:00:46.435 [           main] WARN  impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl
Could not get localhost address
org.moqui.BaseException: Could not get localhost address
```

I use Opensuse OS. I can't not run, compile Moqui Framework because error above.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning and if all else is working with the URL writing for screens and such you can ignore it. If there are issues you can make it work by specifying a domain name in the webapp.@http-host and/or @https-host attributes in your runtime Moqui Conf XML file, which in the case above is the MoquiDevConf.xml file.